# Why do we call the axiom Br in modal logic "Platonic Thesis"?

Tags: logic

The Axiom Br (or B) in modal logic is sometimes called "Platonic Thesis", I wonder it is because of its semantical property (being symmetrical) but I couldn't find anything related.

Comment: Platonic ??? See [Modal Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/#ModLog): "The system **B** (for the logician Brouwer) is formed by adding axiom (B) to M : **A→◻◊A**."

Comment: Yes, I saw it in Rod Girles book (Modal Logics and Philosophy), it seems strange to me because Brouwer's thesis is totally anti-platonic.

Comment: It may derive from epistemic interpretation of ◻ as "known" or "provable". Then inferring from the truth of A that it is provable that it is not disprovable would appeal to some platonistic notion of truth.